Dynamic Data in Coulomb Counting
I am trying to use Coulomb Counting method to estimate the SoC of Li-Ion battery pack. The pack has around 100 cells in parallel-series connection. Will it be possible to use the dynamic current (I) values (when the battery is running, the real time I values are taken from an analogue front end board and fed to the Coulomb counting algorithm running in the PC). Is Coulomb counting algorithm capable of handling the real-time I values or is it good only with stored I values?
I tried using already stored lab test data (current(I) values), to find SoC using Coulomb counting method. Now, I want to know if I can follow the same Coulomb Counting method, to feed real time data (received from analogue front end (AFE) while the battery is running in real time) to find SoC. Will that be appropriate? Or should I choose any other method to process the dynamic (real-time) inputs.
